# How do I match an attribute value to a JSON value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've got a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "DocID": "NA2", 
  "DocType": "Phase1.1 - Visa Documents (This section is applicable for HK work location only)", 
  "DocSubType": "New Application", 
  "DocName": "Passport / Travel Document (Soft copy only) *", 
  "DocDescription": ""
}
```

In my HTML I have set the `data-docid` atttribute in a `td` as the `DocID` key's value (in another API call)

Now, I want to compare if `value.DocID` is equal (`==`) to the `docid` and insert `DocSubType` in that particular `td`.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: docuViewURL,
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      console.log(index);
      var a = $("#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(index)").attr("data-docid");
      var b = value.DocID;
      if (a == b) {
        // then
      }
    });
  }
});
```

It doesn't work and even the `index` variable won't give me the output for `var a` instead I get `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong and what can I change.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried to do this in for loop but loop start from 0 and check value. if `i=0` then DocID = 1 and in td if its 2 then its fail

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code you've used to achieve your objective. Please also include a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: Start by switching `"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(index)"` by `"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(" + index +")"`

Comment: Sorry silly mistake !!! yet output is undefined

Comment: are you able to get any values if you replace the index with actual value, just for debugging purpose.

Comment: It will be good if you share html also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you're not inserting your index variable into your selector.

This is a [concatenated string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Long_literal_strings):

```
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(" + index + ")"
```

This is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(${index})`
```

This is a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Syntax):

```
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(index)"
```

You're using a string literal containing the word *"index"* to select the desired element when you should be using a concatenated string or a template literal to insert the `index` variable into your selector string.

Another problem is that you're passing a string instead of a number to the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector.

This is because you're using the [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function wrong.

You're looping through a (JSON) object, not an array, there is no index, there are keys, and in your case the keys are strings (**E.G**: *"DocID"*, *"DocType"*, *"DocSubType"*, etc, etc).

So even if you do properly insert the `index` variable into your selector, these are the selectors you'll end up with:

```
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(DocID)"
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(DocType)"
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(DocSubType)"
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(DocName)"
"#candidateDetails tbody td a:eq(DocDescription)"
```

You solve this problem (and save yourself a lot of trouble) by using an attribute selector instead of the `:eq()` selector, like this:

```
"#candidateDetails tbody td a[data-docid]"
```

This prevents you from manually having to specify the index of your elements, giving you more freedom with the positioning of elements in your HTML.

Another thing is that your code doesn't explicitly state that this is a JSON GET request.

Sure jQuery *might* be smart enough to tell what kind of request this is but as the old saying goes, [explicit is better than implicit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Features_and_philosophy) and that doesn't just apply to Python programs.

I'd advice you to use the [`jQuery.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function, which is explicitly meant to create JSON GET requests, instead.

Replace your Ajax request with this:

```
jQuery.getJSON(docuViewURL, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // NOTE: cache elements not values
    var link = $("#candidateDetails tbody td a[data-docid]");
    // NOTE: if you're only going to use a value once, there's no need to cache it
    // NOTE: use `data("x")` instead of `attr("data-x")` for more concise code
    if (link.length > 0 && link.data("docid") == value.DocID) {
      // do stuff with the link
    }
  });
});
```

You could also get rid of the `data()` function and use an attribute selector:

```
jQuery.getJSON(docuViewURL, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // get the link and check to see if it exists
    var link = $("#candidateDetails tbody td a[data-docid='" + value.DocID + "']");
    if (link.length > 0) {
      // do stuff with the link
    }
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** if you need more information, the [jQuery API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) has a search bar that you can use to find documentation for functions you're struggling with.

**NOTE:** I'm not trying to be rude or insult you but I think it would go a long way if you read the [MDN JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) which would help you understand the basics and fundamentals of JavaScript.

**NOTE:** there are also [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML) and [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS) guides.

Good luck and remember to keep your code [DRY, SOLID and Simple](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/73069).

Comment: @AtalShrivastava What's not working? What error are you getting? What part of my answer have you tried?

Comment: `$("#candidateDetails tbody td a[data-docid]");` this doesn't return me all value. the loop break in between. because there are `td`s which doesn't have docid attribute

Comment: Have you tried using the second code example? The one with the following code: `$("#candidateDetails tbody td a[data-docid='" + value.DocID + "']");`.

Comment: i don't have to reset the value for docid. value is already there

Comment: Could you try using `console.log` to see what the `data` variable outputs?

Comment: it's just return me single value

Comment: But ***what*** is the value?

Comment: @AtalShrivastava What do the `key` and `value` variables return, also what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jquery 3.3.1, problem is my loop break in between of that i'm not getting all id's. i tried with attribute selector also.

Comment: Have you tried checking your HTML? Could there be something wrong there?

Comment: thanks man its working. thanks for your help. problem is with the sequence of API's